# Associating multiple data with a single entry in Open Office Base

Tags: openoffice, database

I'm trying to build a database that I can use to track prices of groceries on certain dates.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to have a single entry associate with multiple data.
For example, carrots.  The index would be carrots.  Then, a few categorizing fields (ie, Produce|Vegetable)  Then, I can enter a price, date that the price was valid, store that was selling for said price, etc.  And the next time I buy carrots, I can just add a new set of pricing data that would be associated with the original carrots entry.
I know very little about database building, so if anyone has something I could just modify, I would greatly appreciate it.  Alternatively, a step by step tutorial would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have a `tblProducts` that contains a primary key, the product name and pricing. Then in your `tblPurchases` include a column that references the primary key in `tblProducts`.

What I would recommend is something along the lines of a [snowflake schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) design.

[image: With thanks to Wikipedia]